# Jquery onclick prevent defaut behaviour

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I'm writing a function :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.openBox = function(theId) {
    // do something
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and several links calling my function like this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).openBox('#theBoxId');">Open the box !</a>
```

I know I can prevent default behaviour with ***return false*** :

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).openBox('#theBoxId'); return false">Open the box !</a>
```

But I want to put it in my jQuery function...
I've tested with event.target but it doesn't seems to work...

Answer (score 1):

You can `return false;` inside your `openBox` plugin, and return the value of *that* in your `onclick` attribute;

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.openBox = function(theId) {
        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and then:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return $(this).openBox('#theBoxId');">Open the box !</a>
```

However, this is **far** from ideal. jQuery is expected to be chainable; but by returning `false` rather than `this`, you can no longer do: `$('foo').openBox().trigger('change')` and the like.

What you ***should*** be doing is attaching an event [*the jQuery way*](http://api.jquery.com/on), capturing [the event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and calling [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
jQuery.fn.openBox = function (id) {
    return this.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // now open your box `id`.
    });
}

$('a').openBox('#theBoxId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onclick` in the element, put the selector in a data attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-openbox="#theBoxId">Open the box !</a>
```

Then bind a click event for all links with that data:

```
$(function(){
  $('a[data-openbox]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this).data('openbox');
    // do something
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/EjLsQ/