# How do you extend jQuery's Event.preventDefault() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extend jQuery's Event object's method preventDefault.

```
jQuery.Event.prototype.preventDefault
```

However, when I try to overwrite the function, even with its default method, it doesn't work correctly.

```
jQuery.Event.prototype.preventDefault = function() {
var e=this.originalEvent;this.isDefaultPrevented=it,e&&(e.preventDefault e.preventDefault():e.returnValue=!1)
}
```

This post is close, but I'd rather just extend the preventDefault function itself:
[Jquery onclick prevent defaut behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312848/jquery-onclick-prevent-defaut-behaviour)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: preventDefault() is pure js method....

Comment: Why? it works perfect to do as is intended. Why on earth would you want to extend it? I have a feeling your solution would be much more simple and more to point than rewriting the Library if you'd tell us more of what you are trying to do. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @C-linkNepal Normally, yes. But `jQuery.Event`s are not. The `preventDefault` you call in a jQuery event handler is not the pure JS method

Comment: @SpYk3HH Current codebase uses a lot of e.preventDefault in unsuspected places. Adding a console.log(this.currentTarget) can help debugging, at least in our case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var originalPreventDefault = jQuery.Event.prototype.preventDefault;
jQuery.Event.prototype.preventDefault = function () { 
  // TODO: new code here

  return originalPreventDefault.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Method overriding/extension is usually done this way no matter the method's content.